# Access Treenode using Rowkey

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I  have the rowkey(say 0_0,0_1,etc) of treenodes, now is there any simple way to get the node with that  rowkey  or we need to iterate over entire treenode.

the below code doesn't work

```
private TreeNode getNode(TreeNode node, String key) {
    for(TreeNode child : node.getChildren()){
        if(key.equals(child.getRowKey())) 
            return child;
        return getNode(child,key);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: get the rowkey with select click ?!?

Comment: @YagamiLight Im able to get the rowkey on drag in javascript. now im passing that rowkey to bean method, My question is how to get the associated treenode using the passed rowkey, in bean side

Comment: please edit your question to include this information (it is a valuable one) i faced this problem and i am sorry to tell you that it's impossible and i will give more details in my answer

Comment: If iterating is to expensive, keep a map in memory with the rowkey as key?

Comment: @Kukeltje he use a `JavaScrpit` method to get the Id it's the same thing

Comment: @Kukeltje please provide a link to read more about how it's working thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make it short as possible it's impossible to get the `node` with the `rowkey` because the type of informations that you pass from your `JSF` page to your `been` it's a `String` one that mean it's impossible to retrieve any data from this informations, like you said in your question the only solution that you have is to loop in your `tree` to search for it.